# Default to index page when navigating to a Document Library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a public internet site created in SharePoint 2010. I have uploaded an index.html web page to a Document Library, which I will call "abc." Here is what I want to happen:

www.website.com/abc >> should automatically direct to index.html in that library.

Instead, when I go to that URL, I am asked to log in. My usual login information that I use to edit the site, however, has no effect, and I am eventually just taken to blank white page.

If I type the full URL, www.website.com/abc/index.html, it goes to the correct page, so I know it has been published.

The index.html page is the only item in the document library.

The web address listed in the Document Library settings is http://www.website.com/abc/Forms/AllItems.aspx. I think this is what I need to change to get it to default to index.html. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint document libraries can only have default views for their default pages.   Can you create a view to make your changes there, or edit the default view?

If not, you could always edit the default view in Sharepoint Designer and put a redirect to your page, but that's kind of hackish.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited the default view (which I named Redirect) in SharePoint Designer and put this code on it (removing all other code):

`<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
      Response.Redirect("index.html");
      base.OnLoad(e);
  }
</script>`

I received this error: "An error occurred during the processing of /abc/Forms/Redirect.aspx. Code blocks are not allowed in this file."

I'm not very familiar with ASP, so not sure how to bug fix. I realize this may not be the ideal solution but a quick fix is fine for now.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a [javascript redirect](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)..

Comment: Thanks. I realized the ASP was probably the problem and changed it to a standard HTML redirect. That seems to work, on the staging server at least. Once published, though, the Redirect view is asking me to log in... that is probably a separate issue though.

Comment: Is the page checked in?  I know you're new here, so don't forget to mark as answer if this solved your problem :)

Comment: Yes, page was checked in. Thanks!